# Verifying that the user inputs and integer C++

Tags: c++, input, verification

My C++ program needs to ask the user to input two values. In order to avoid non-integer values, I wanted to create a loop like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
     int x,y;

     while ((typeof(x)!=int){
         cin>>x;
         cin>>y;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

However, it does not work. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: That may be what you want to do, but completely wrong on how you actually accomplish this. Type association is a compile-time thing, not a runtime thing. If you're expecting an `int` , then you should try to read an `int`. If it works, great. if it didn't, you clean up whatever is left in the input stream, reset the stream state, and try again (usually after prompting the user of the error of their ways).

Comment: "it does not work" is not a sufficiently detailed diagnostic. What, _specifically_ is the problem?

Comment: In C++, a data type needs to be known at compile time.

Comment: `int x,y;` makes `x` an `int`. Nothing can change that. You need to test `cin>>x;` It will fail if the user did not provide an `int`. If it fails, you need to clean up by `clear`ing the error flag and removing the non-`int` from `cin` before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't evaluate any datatype directly as an expression.

Use `std::cin.good()` (returns boolean) for verification if the number(s) entered were integer.

```
int val1, val2;

std::cout << "Input two integers: ";
std::cin >> val1 >> val2;

while (!std::cin.good()) {
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

    std::cout << "Incorrect! Input two integers: ";
    std::cin >> val1 >> val2;
}

std::cout << val1 << ' ' << val2;
```

> **Sample Output**

```
Input two integers: 33 h
Incorrect! Input two integers: l h
Incorrect! Input two integers: 1 2
1 2
```

Comment: Rather than call `std::cin.good()` directly, you should use `while (!(std::cin >> val1 >> val2))` instead. And `INT_MAX` needs to be `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()` instead.

Comment: Thanks, do you know which header I must include to use it?

Comment: @fxalban8 to use what?